# Explanation of .Net 4 Tasks with Callback Parallel Programming

Tags: .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

If I have a system where it uses tasks that are independent of each other; I want to run multiple tasks at once(I do not want the second task to run when the first to finish). Is there a way to do this with the concept of parallel programming?

Also, is there a way to use callbacks to notify me when the tasks are complete?

Explainations of each concept would be appreciated.

Comment: Luckily, Microsoft has put together a whole library on this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing *asynchrony* and *parallelism*.

You can run multiple delegates in parallel using the methods in the `Parallel` class.
These are synchronous methods that will run on the calling thread as well,  so there is no need for a callback.